# Replace window when script ends JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, replace

Is there a way I can insert:

```
location.replace("https://www.google.com");
```

After all the functions in my javascript have run, aka when my script ends? I've tried putting it in different parts of my script but it just replaces it straight away.
This is my script currently (sorry it's so long its a text adventure game):

```js
var currentFrame = 0;
var images = document.getElementById("images"); 
var text = document.getElementById("text"); 
var buttonBox = document.getElementById('buttonBox');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
//this is the variable for the name of the character
var yerdog;



//this is how after we type in the character name and hit enter
//we will add the name to the variable, remove the input box and start our first scenario
input.onkeypress = function(event) {
  console.log(input.value);
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    yerdog =  input.value;
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    advanceTo(scenario.two)
  }
};


//this changes the text and puts in your characters name
var changeText = function(words) {
  text.innerHTML = words.replace("Your dog", yerdog);
};

//this takes the image link and puts it in the proper format, sending it to the html
var changeImage = function(img) {
  images.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
};


//this looks at the number of options we have set and creates enough buttons 
var changeButtons = function(buttonList) {
  buttonBox.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
    buttonBox.innerHTML += "<button onClick="+buttonList[i][1]+">" + buttonList[i][0] + "</button>";
  };
};

//this is what moves the game along
var advanceTo = function() {
  if (currentFrame >= scenario.length) {
    //finish the game code here:
    location.replace("https://www.google.com");
  }
  
  var s = scenario[currentFrame];
  changeImage(s.image)
  changeText(s.text)
  changeButtons(s.buttons)
};


var scenario = [
  one: {
    image: "https://s9.postimg.org/eceo9mp73/5860028206_d66810105f_b.jpg", //dog
    text: "You have finally decided to take your dog out for a walk. You smile and pat your trusty companion's head. What the dog's name?\n",
  },

  
];
input.onkeypress = function(event) {
  console.log(input.value);
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    yerdog =  input.value;
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    currentFrame = currentFrame + 1;  // <--- here
    advanceTo() // <-- and here
  }
};

//this is the code that starts the game
advanceTo(scenario.one);
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: It wont let me delete it because people have answered it.

Comment: @samson24 Take a moment and read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403803

Comment: DON'T USE the `script` tag! Every SO question is about scripts one way or another

Answer (score 1):

You can use ifelse statement as well as timeout for it

```
setTimeout ( "location()", 5000 );

function location( )
{
  location.replace("https://www.google.com");  
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me it broke the rest of my js :/

Comment: where you placed it? You have added your code in question but where you are setting up location.replace You must have main function.

Comment: I put it at the start of my script but it broke the rest of my code

Comment: make the main function and create ifelse condition in it where the code successfully runs at the end paste setTimeout with location.replace.

Comment: @Tayyabmehar you have typos 1. `location` is a reserved word 2.You are not calling `location()` in the `setTimeout`, it is just a string and does nothing. and this is not an accurate solution for the OP question

Answer (score 1):

```js
var currentFrame = 0;
var images = document.getElementById("images"); 
var text = document.getElementById("text"); 
var buttonBox = document.getElementById('buttonBox');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
//this is the variable for the name of the character
var yerdog;


var scenario = [
{
    image: "https://s9.postimg.org/eceo9mp73/5860028206_d66810105f_b.jpg", //dog
    text: "You have finally decided to take your dog out for a walk. You smile and pat your trusty companion's head. What the dog's name?\n",
    buttons: [],
  },
]


//this changes the text and puts in your characters name
var changeText = function(words) {
  text.innerHTML = words.replace("Your dog", yerdog);
};

//this takes the image link and puts it in the proper format, sending it to the html
var changeImage = function(img) {
  images.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
};


//this looks at the number of options we have set and creates enough buttons 
var changeButtons = function(buttonList) {
  buttonBox.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
    buttonBox.innerHTML += "<button onClick="+buttonList[i][1]+">" + buttonList[i][0] + "</button>";
  }
};

//this is what moves the game along
var advanceTo = function() {
  if (currentFrame >= scenario.length) {
    //finish the game code here:
    console.log("end of the game");
    //location.replace("https://www.google.com"); // uncomment on your page
    return;
  }
  var s = scenario[currentFrame];
  changeImage(s.image)
  changeText(s.text)
  changeButtons(s.buttons)
};



input.onkeypress = function(event) {
  console.log(input.value);
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    yerdog =  input.value;
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    currentFrame = currentFrame + 1;  // <--- here
    advanceTo() // <-- and here
  }
};

//this is the code that starts the game
advanceTo();
```

```html
<div id="images"></div>
<div id="text"></div>
<div id="buttonBox"></div>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
```

Based on the code your posted you have 3 important parts:

- the `advanceTo` function
- the `input.onkeypress` event
- the scenario list

for that I can suggest one of two changes:

- change the scenario to an array (end and call the `replace` when there is no more elements)
- add a `end` scenario (that calls the `replace` when it comes to it)

#### Array approach:

you can change the scenario to an array instead an object:

```
var scenario = [
  {
    image: "https://s9.postimg.org/eceo9mp73/5860028206_d66810105f_b.jpg", //dog
    text: "You have finally decided to take your dog out for a walk. You smile and pat your trusty companion's head. What the dog's name?\n",
  },
  {
    image: "https://s9.postimg.org/eceo9mp73/5860028206_d66810105f_b.jpg", //dog
    text: "You have finally decided to take your dog out for a walk. You smile and pat your trusty companion's head. What the dog's name?\n",
  },
]
```

Also store the current frame in a variable (I suggest at the top of your code):

```
var currentFrame = 0;
```

So you can call advanceTo and starting the game (we are not passing the index anymore because is stored in the `currentFrame` variable:

```
advanceTo()
```

and change the logic of the advanced to a little bit:

```
var advanceTo = function() {
  if (currentFrame >= scenario.length) {
    //finish the game code here:
    location.replace("https://www.google.com");
    return;
  }
  
  var s = scenario[currentFrame];
  changeImage(s.image)
  changeText(s.text)
  changeButtons(s.buttons)
};
```

At the end, you need to change your `input.onkeypress` event:

```
input.onkeypress = function(event) {
  console.log(input.value);
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    yerdog =  input.value;
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    currentFrame = currentFrame + 1;  // <--- here
    advanceTo() // <-- and here
  }
};
```